# ofstream a file in same level directory in C++

Tags: c++, windows, ofstream

I checked for forums but I found like this:

```
ofstream outfile;
outfile.open ("test.txt");
outfile.open ("\\data\\test.txt");
```

But I want to open a file in same level directory. How can I do this?

My C++ exe file is in release directory, I need to open a file in log directory.

```
root
-somefolder
--release
--test
--log
```

This didn't worked:

```
outfile.open(".\\log\\test.txt",ios::app)
```

Comment: One dot is the current directory.

Comment: Yep. When in doubt type the entire location where the file resides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `outfile.open("..\\log\\test.txt",ios::app)`